# How to deal with missing libcrypt.so.1 on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, glibc

How do you deal with a missing `libcrypt.so.1` on Arch Linux?

Trying to run `openoffice4` (the [LibreOffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) binary) results in:

```
/opt/openoffice4/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file `libcrypt.so.1` indeed does not exist. There is, however:

```
└[/usr/lib]> ls -al libcrypt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Dec 18 11:31 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2999144 Dec 18 11:31 libcrypto.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 Feb  3 12:16 libcryptsetup.so -> libcryptsetup.so.12.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 Feb  3 12:16 libcryptsetup.so.12 -> libcryptsetup.so.12.7.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  484192 Feb  3 12:16 libcryptsetup.so.12.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Feb  2 08:12 libcrypt.so -> libcrypt.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Feb  2 08:12 libcrypt.so.2 -> libcrypt.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  165824 Feb  2 08:12 libcrypt.so.2.0.0
```

Simply creating a new symlink to `libcrypt.so.1` fails as this is the incorrect version:

```
/opt/openoffice4/program/javaldx: /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `GLIBC_2.2.5' not found (required by /opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice.bin: /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `GLIBC_2.2.5' not found (required by /opt/openoffice4/program/libuno_sal.so.3)
```

I've tried to see what package provides `libcrypt.so.1` using `pacman -F`:

Which is:

```
core/glibc 2.33-5 [installed: 2.35-2]
    usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1
core/lib32-glibc 2.33-5 [installed: 2.35-2]
    usr/lib32/libcrypt.so.1
community/aarch64-linux-gnu-glibc 2.34-1
    usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libcrypt.so.1
community/riscv64-linux-gnu-glibc 2.32-1 (risc-v)
    usr/riscv64-linux-gnu/lib/libcrypt.so.1
```

The latter two are not applicable to me as the architecture is different.

Reinstalling glibc and lib32-glibc didn't resolve my issue. Moreover, checking with `pacman -Ql` to see if the file in question (`libcrypt.so.1`) is actually present in glibc and lib32-glibc, doesn't show it exists.

This problem appears to have occurred after an update which pulled in a newer version of glibc:

```
[ALPM] upgraded glibc (2.33-5 -> 2.35-2)
```

I've also tried to simply reinstall LibreOffice. Nothing changes.

Comment: Another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255233/1655478

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by installing the [libxcrypt-compat](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/libxcrypt-compat/) package, which is now available from the [core](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Official_repositories#core) repository.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment yet, so I'm extending the correct [answers by pokoli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691997/501950) [and by Gilles Quenot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728500/501950) here.

To [install the `libxcrypt-compat`](https://arch.pkgs.info/guide/how-to-install-libxcrypt-compat-with-cli-on-arch-linux-manjaro-anarchy) you're missing with cli on arch (or manjaro), you can use [one of these among others](https://arch.pkgs.info/guide/how-to-install-libxcrypt-compat-with-cli-on-arch-linux-manjaro-anarchy):

```bash
## Using pacman
# pacman needs to be run with root privilege (sudo):
sudo pacman -S core/libxcrypt-compat

## Using yay
# Stating repository (Core) to prevent installing the incorrect package:

yay -S --repo core/libxcrypt-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

To search a specific needed missing file on archlinux:

```
$ pkgfile -s libcrypt.so.1
core/libxcrypt-compat
community/aarch64-linux-gnu-glibc
community/riscv64-linux-gnu-glibc
```